# When combining 2 strings, Dom element is not showing same results as static entered query

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm sure I'm overlooking the most obvious, but I need to loop through a few links on the page, but some reason when I try to introduce the iterated number, and change to a string, it doesn't work.  By not working, I mean when I run the function, it gives me error ' Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null'.  The first is an example showing it works without the loop.  The 2nd is the string combo that doesn't work.

This works!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var grids = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow')
  setInterval(function(){ 
    for(i=1;i<grids.length;i++) {
      var test = '_resultsGrid__Button_1'
      document.getElementById(test).click()
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

This doesn't!

```
function myFunction() {
  var grids = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow')
  setInterval(function() { 
    for(i=1;i<grids.length;i++) {
      var test = '_resultsGrid__Button_' + String(i)
      document.getElementById(String(test)).click()
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Is the loop & elements the same on both? There's no reason one of these would work differently than the other

Comment: Ah; I had second thoughts on it being as the first one had worked, so figured I would ask for clarity - Glad I could help

Comment: You explained it earlier, but what was your reasoning on this not working with my 2nd example?

Comment: If you only have one element on the page that matches your selector, `grids.length` will be 1 - and your loop currently only runs when `i` is *less than* the length (1)

Comment: Generally both code should work. The error means that the program haven't found an element with the given ID. Are you sure that all elements exist and have the specified IDs? Without seeing the relevant part of your HTML, it's hard to tell exactly what's gone wrong... Side note: usually you don't have to use `String()`, implicit type conversion ensures the values concatenated as you expect (if at least one operand of `+` is a string), and `.getElementById` takes a string as well.

Comment: @FZs yea the site is an internal web site, and I understand your last comment about the 2 strings, that merely shows almost overkill of what I was trying.  Not sure either, but I've ran through it a few times and it would not work, basically it couldn't find the click,  The iteration kept going through, but when I ran Light's addition, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing

```js
for (i = 1;i < grids.length;i++) { ... }
```

You should be doing

```js
for (i = 1;i <= grids.length;i++) { ... }
```

In your first example you were looping only while `i` was [`less than (<)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Less_than_operator) the elements length, so you would loop one less time than the length; you'll want to use the [`less than or equal to (<=)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Less_than_or_equal_operator) operator instead to include that last iteration

---

```
function myFunction() {
  var grids = document.getElementsByClassName('gridRow')

  setInterval(function() { 
    for(i = 1; i <= grids.length; i++) {
      var test = '_resultsGrid__Button_'+String(i)
      document.getElementById(String(test)).click()
    }
  }, 2000);
}
```